# Can not print the sign @ when using biblatex (author year style)

Tags: biblatex, symbols

I am using biblatex author year style and in my text I have an @ which biber does not like giving me error as below:

```
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\TEMPLE~1.000\AppData\Local
\Temp\biber_tmp_kM22\658097ff4c951e70db95e86474283432_17340.utf8, line 25, 
syntax error: found "using", expected one of: start of entry ("{" or "(") or 
quoted string ({...} or "...")
```

Below is the code.
To run:  step1: pdflatex step 2: biber step3: pdflatex.

If you delete the symbole @ in the text the code works fine and we see the bibliography at the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
 % to run: step1: pdflatex step 2: biber step3: pdflatex
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
author       = { my author},
date         = { 2020},
title        = {my title},
publisher    = {city:press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}
I can not print  @ when using biblatex.(\textcite{mybook})
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: \@ wont work either with biber

Comment: That is kind of a weird error. Try `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`

Comment: Ooooh. I see. without the extension it picks up `\jobname.tex` and tries to use that as a data source. `\jobname.tex` is obviously not a valid bib file, so `biber` errors.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPurton You solved the problem.

Comment: @DavidPurton If you like you can write the solution below then I accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\addbibresource` requires a full file name, so you should use `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`.

Without this `biber` picks up `\jobname.tex` and tries to use this as a `bib` file. Obviously, this isn't a valid `bib` file, so `biber` generates an error. In particular, `biber` doesn't like the `@` because that character is meant to mark the start of a `bib` record.

I have a feeling that `biblatex` used to allow `\addbibresource{\jobname}` but the documentation always specified the extension to be provided, so maybe a recent code clean up tightened the requirements.

Comment: I think `\addbibresource` has always needed the `.bib` file extension. It was added in version 1.2 back in 2011 and the documentation explicitly mentions having to include the extension as you say. I saw `\addbibresource{\jobname}` as a trick to avoid the `.bib` file (so that Biber reads the `.tex` file and ignores everything but the bib entries as junk) in the `biblatex-nejm` documentation and [apparently it has used that since 2011](https://github.com/bcbi/biblatex-nejm/blob/288210762c720d39db8b94ffc28793f5c3e11826/biblatex-nejm.tex), so I'd guess there was no change here.